# EF6 reading many to many relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, many-to-many

There are many questions on almost this scenario but i was not able to solve my problem with that help. My models looks like this

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

I configured entities in dbcontext as below

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
    .HasMany<Tag>(t => t.Tags)
    .WithMany(m => m.Posts)
    .Map(mp =>
    {
        mp.ToTable("PostToTag");
        mp.MapLeftKey("PostId");
        mp.MapRightKey("TagId");
    });
```

When i run following query, I can read postid and even i can read related TagId but Name property of Tag is always empty, it never gets loaded with tag name

```
    var posts = db.Posts
    .Include(t => t.Tags)
    .ToList();
```

I simplified code here both entities have HashSet in constructor and also tried lazy loading on/off but no success.

Comment: Hum... Weird. Columns get always loaded when you're not doing projection to a DTO/ViewModel. Take a look at your Tag table and show us the content. I think the column is empty there.

Comment: Ahh, how goof I'm, I did not check the table, my insert action added new tags with empty names, as i was not expecting that but did not check, thanks